# Installing tensorflow from PyCharm virtual env

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, virtualenv

I am trying to install tensorflow through the PyCharm virtualenv. However, I got the following message:

[image]

Any idea how I could fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't easy to read the trace from this image. Please post the trace.

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solution by Pycharm, i.e. install tensorflow under this virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was using Python 3.7, which tensorflow doesn't support yet. Change to Python 3.6 and everything works.